# How to animate a color change of a pie apexchart in a vue project?

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I got a pie chart I made with Apexcharts in a vue project, and I want to alter the colors of the pie sections and have those changes be dispayed with a transition. There are transitions when I change the values of the pie segments, but there are no transitions used when I change the segments colors.

The chart object of the options has animations set up as specified in the documentation. The updateOptions() method has "animate" set to true by default. Still it doesn't work. I also tried giving the matching elements a transition via CSS, and that works for cases such as hover, but it doesn't work when I update the charts options.